# New at using Visual Studio, how to add tables to a DB?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, database-design

I have a school assignment where we are to fill in some SQL-statements in a code we got from our teacher. We are also to make tree different tables into a db which already exists. When I try to make a new class for adding these tables I think Im doing something wrong. The tables re never created. Why?!

DB CONNECTION:

```
Public Class ClassConnection
'Mot citrix
Dim Koppling As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=EmbeddedVB; Data Source=LUiis02; Integrated Security=true")
'Mot access
'Dim Koppling As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=Poster.mdb")
'lokalt mot SQL-server
'Dim Koppling As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=Testar;Data Source=(local); Integrated Security=true;")

Public ReadOnly Property ReturneraKoppling() As SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Get
        Return Koppling
    End Get
End Property

Sub open()
    Koppling.Open()
End Sub

Sub close()
    Koppling.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

TABLES (for creating)

```
Public Class Tables
Private mySqlConnection As New ClassConnection
Private myAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
Private mySqlCommand As New SqlCommand
Private ds As DataSet
Private gammaltPnr As String

Public Sub fyllDB()
    mySqlCommand.Connection = mySqlConnection.ReturneraKoppling()
    mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    mySqlConnection.open()
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST Kurs4918(" &
        "kursnamn char(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY " &
        ")"
    myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    mySqlConnection.close()

    mySqlConnection.open()
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST Elev4918 (" &
        "pnr char(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " &
        "fornamn char(20), " &
        "efternamn char(20), " &
        "ort char(15) " &
        ") "
    myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    mySqlConnection.close()

    mySqlConnection.open()
    mySqlCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST KursElev4918(" &
        "pnr char(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, " &
        "kursnamn char(30) " &
        ") "
    myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)
    mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    mySqlConnection.close()

End Sub
```

The startup Form1.vb (this should run fyllDB() from Tables right?....

```
Public Class frmMain
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
Private db As New Tables

Private Sub fill()
    db.fyllDB()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes there are no constraints, but I dont know what it is?A plug-in?

Comment: It is the newest replacement for ado.net. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/184133/Using-Entity-Framework-4-1-Code-First-with-an-exisv (replacement might not be the exact word)

Answer (score 0):

Your CREATE TABLE and DROP TABLE statements are not quite right. If you have SQL Server Management Studio, you can use it to see how to make those statements: right-click an existing table in the Object Explorer pane and choosing "Script Table as..."->"DROP and CREATE to"->"New Query Editor Window". You will get something similar to

```
USE [testing]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[testTable]    Script Date: 11/21/2012 20:35:02 ******/
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[testTable]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[testTable]
GO

USE [testing]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[testTable]    Script Date: 11/21/2012 20:35:02 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable](
    [number] [int] NULL,
    [str] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [tim] [time](7) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

From which you should be able to pick out the parts you need.

To execute the DROP/CREATE statements, use the [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx).

EDIT:

Thus, your FyllDb method would be more like this:

```
Public Sub FyllDb()
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim sqlConn = New SqlConnection("Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testing;Trusted_Connection=True;")
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn

    sqlCmd.CommandText = "IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[testTable2]') AND type in (N'U')) DROP TABLE [dbo].[testTable2]"

    Try
        sqlConn.Open()
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error deleting table: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Try

    sqlCmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable2]( [number] [int] NULL, [str] [nchar](10) NULL, [tim] [time](7) NULL) ON [PRIMARY]"

    Try
        sqlConn.Open()
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As ArgumentException
        MsgBox("Error creating table: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        sqlConn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub
```

-- tested as working with VS2012/SQL Server 2008 R2 Express/Windows 7 x64.

Please adjust to your table definition.

Comment: Grear answer, I will download the software try this and come back with an update!

Comment: I have downloaded it and tried it but dont really get it, since i dont have login detail to the server so I cant use the statements you were talking about, I found something that were similr, called templates. The create template is very different from some solutions i found online, i added in the bottom of my post (edited) another try, is that completely wrong too?

Comment: As you can see I use both:  myAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(mySqlCommand)
        mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() to execute cause I dont know which one to use. But when I run the program and try to do something it shuts down giving me a sql error which still leads me to think that they are never created. In my startup file I have:  Private db As New Tables

    Private Sub fill()
        db.fyllDB()
    End Sub
Which should create the tables on startup?

Comment: @EmanuelOlsson I don't know if you get notified when I edit my answer, so this comment should do that.